# Running Wireshark (Monitor Mode) using Live DVD

Tags: live-cd, livedvd, wireshark

I'm having trouble installing/running Wireshark to capture traffic other than my own.   I've tried multiple usb-wifi adapters*, so not sure if it's a driver, hardware, or an installation issue.    For example, do I need another program to run first (airmon-ng, acrylic, etc)?

I haven't found any any current guide on installing/running Wireshark in monitor mode for ubuntu 14.04 live...  The guides I've found are a bit old and are not for livedvd.
http://www.willhackforsushi.com/books/377_eth_2e_06.pdf

I know the nst22 live fedora distro has wireshark pre-installed, but has limited  driver support.

*Usb Netgear A6200 (Broadcom BCM43526), 6 Realtek based devices: RT3070/RT3072/RT3290/RT5370/RTL8187L/RTL8188cus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example, do I need another program to run first (airmon-ng

Yes.  Sadly, turning monitor mode on isn't as simple as it is in, say, OS X; you have to go through an elaborate dance involving creating new interfaces associated with the real Wi-Fi interface and setting them up as monitor-mode interfaces, and that involves netlink, and the "easy" way of doing netlink involves a library that has apparently changed its API 3 times, in incompatible ways, so linking libpcap with libnl is a bad idea and few if any distributions do it, so turning monitor mode on in tcpdump/Wireshark/TShark/etc. isn't as easy as "use the -I command line option" or "check the monitor mode box" or....

So see [the Linux section of the Wireshark Wiki's "CaptureSetup/WLAN" page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN#Linux).